# Bilinear form associated to Coxeter group

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, reflection, coxeter-groups

Let me just set the scene before asking my question.

Let V be a real vector space with basis $u_1,...,u_n $. Let $W$ be a Coxeter group with generating set $S=\{s_1, ..., s_n \}$ and let $m_{ij}=|s_is_j|$. Let $B$ be the bilinear form on $V$ defined by $B(u_i, u_j)=-\cos(\pi / m_{ij})$. Let $\sigma_i$ be the linear map on $V$ where $\sigma_i(x)=x-2B(u_i, x)u_i$.

Then $\sigma_i$ is the reflection with respect to the hyperplane $H_i=\{v \in V : B(u_i, v)=0 \}. $

I am trying to show that the order of $\sigma_i \sigma_j$ is $m_{ij}$.

I am reading a proof of this and it shows if we let $P$ be the span of $u_i$ and $u_j$ then $V=P \oplus P^{\perp}$ where $P^{\perp} = \{u \in V : B(u, v)=0 \text{ for all } v \in P \}.$ Then the quadratic form $Q$ where $Q(v)=B(v, v)$ is positive-definite and so $B$ is nonsingular on $P$.

Since $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ act trivially on $P^{\perp}$ the order of $\sigma_i \sigma_j$ is just equal to the order of $\sigma_i \sigma_j $ restricted to $P$.

**My problem**

It then says that since $Q$ is positive definite then $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ correspond to reflections in the Euclidean plane.

Since $$B(u_i, u_j )=-\cos(\pi /m_{ij})= \cos(\pi- (\pi/m_{ij}))$$ the angle between the unit vectors $u_i$ and $u_j$ is $\pi-  \pi/m_{ij}$.  I don't understand this bit at all. I don't know why $Q$ being positive-definite means that $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ correspond to reflections in the Euclidean plane and then I don't get how they then deduce that the angle is $2\pi / m_{ij}$. They then go on to say that then this means that $\sigma_i \sigma_j$ corresponds to a rotation through $2\pi / m_{ij}$, I think this comes just from the fact that composing reflections gives a rotation.

Any help with this?

Comment: This is just elementary geometry. For instance the composition of two Euclidean reflections is the rotation by the angle $2\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between the lines of reflection, one normally proves in a Euclidean geometry class. If you have hard time proving this geometrically, just write down matrices for reflections and multiply these.

Comment: Yes this is ok, but I mean how can we view $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ as reflections of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the first place?

Comment: If you took an undergraduate vector analysis class, you probably know the formula for projection of a vector to a line. Use thus to verify that the are indeed reflections.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, it's been a while since I did a vector analysis class, and this is just a side part of a larger proof I'm working on.

Comment: If $(V,B)$ is an inner product space and $H\subset V$ is a hyperplane with the unit normal $n$, then the orthogonal projection of a vector $v\in V$ to $H$ is obtained by the formula $P(v)=v- B(v,n)v$: You subtract from $v$ its normal component. This is completely obvious once you draw a picture and it is something that one learns in a vector calculus class. Now, think, what you get if you subtract from $v$ **twice** its normal component (which is $2B(v,n)v$)? Again, drawing a picture will help.

Comment: This makes sense. How though is the angle between $u_i$ and $u_j$ equal to $\pi - m_{ij}$. I know the formula where $B$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but how does this give the angle with a more general inner product?

Comment: You should consider rereading your linear algebra textbook: any two inner product spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic. You simply cannot be successful in learning Coxeter groups if your linear algebra is shaky.